# Update array with key/values from a different array is not being merged properly

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
<?php

function buildOptions(array $options = []) {
    $supportedOptions = [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'payload' => [],
        'headers' => ['Content-Type: application/json'],
        'url' => 'https://example.com/api',
    ];
    
    // If $options was provided, let's update the above array with values from $options given
    $updatedOptions = array_merge($supportedOptions, $options);
    
    return $updatedOptions;
}

    
$payload = ['Collection' => 'Products'];
    
$input = [
    'headers' => ['X-Api-Token: test'], 
    'url' => 'https://example.com/v2/api',
    'payload' => json_encode($payload),
];

print_r(buildOptions($input));
```

Expected output:

```
[
    'method' => 'POST',
    'payload' => '{"Collection":"Products"}',
    'headers' => ['Content-Type: application/json', 'X-Api-Token: test'],
    'url' => 'https://example.com/v2/api',
]
```

However in the actual output the `'Content-Type: application/json'` gets overrwritten and I want both entries to be there.

Alternatively, is there a better way to do this? I am making a method in a class which accepts various different options to build up the request it sends.  The user doesn't have to provide all the options, only the ones they want updated.  They can also choose not to provide any options at all.  Thanks.

Comment: From the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) on `array_merge`: _If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one._  If you want a multidimensional array inside the result, don't use `array_merge`

Comment: Did you try [array_merge_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) ?

Comment: @Armage hi I didn't know about array_merge_recursive, don't think I've seen it used before.  I only want my $options to append the items if it's an array, otherwise if it's not an array then replace it.  E.g. 'headers' would be an array of items, in which case I want items added to the array not replace the whole array.

Comment: @Michel Hi, is there a function that will append the array items (but only for arrays, not strings) e.g. in my $options the 'headers' value is an array of items, I want items to be appended not replaced

Answer (score 0):

Use this custom merge function (to replace array_merge) :

```
function customMerge($defaultOptions, $customOptions) {
    $finalOptions = $defaultOptions;
    foreach($customOptions as $key => $option) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $defaultOptions)) {
            if (is_array($option)) {
                foreach($option as $subOption) {
                    $finalOptions[$key][] = $subOption;
                }
            }
            else {
                $finalOptions[$key] = $option;
            }
        }
        else {
            $finalOptions[$key] = $option;
        }
    }
    return $finalOptions;
}
```